# How to escape '&' in data coming from webservice in freemarker template?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, freemarker

Freemarker:

If my data is:

```
x = [{
  name= satyajit,
  company = hewlett & packard
}, {
  name= akanksha,
  company = google & co
}]
```

Following is how I want to access the above list in ftl template.

```
${x}
```

But, the above code throws an error saying: The entity name must immediately follow the '&' in the entity reference.

Is there a way to escape the '&' in the data, like the '&' in 'hewlett & packard' from the webservice data in freemarker template?

EDIT:

Error faced:

```
[Fatal Error] NewFile.xml:27:57: The entity name must immediately follow the '&' in the entity reference.
Exception in thread "main" org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/D:/NewFile.xml; lineNumber: 27; columnNumber: 57; The entity name must immediately follow the '&' in the entity reference.
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: try to use `&amp;`

Comment: Hey @Jens, thanks for the response. But using the `&amp;` in my situation won't solve the situation as the data coming from web service cannot be changed to suit the ftl template.

Comment: There' some misunderstanding here. FTL doesn't care what string you insert with `${x}`. It doesn't parse what you insert, it can contain anything, it just prints it to the output. Can we see the actual exception message?

Comment: @ddekany I have included the error as an edit. There is an & in the hashmap I am trying to work with, and so an error is being thrown, which gets solved if I use the ?html built-in.

Comment: That's not thrown by "the above code" (by the FTL code) though, as your question has suggested. Anyway... as you generate XML, not HTML, you should use `?xml` instead of `?html`. Better yet, set the output format of the template to XML (see http://freemarker.org/docs/dgui_quickstart_template.html#dgui_quickstart_template_autoescaping), and it will do the escaping automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching for a while I found that the freemarker builtin [html](http://freemarker.org/docs/ref_builtins_string.html#ref_builtin_html) can solve my situation. In my case here:

`${x?html}`

Answer (score 1):

Wrap blocks of text in <#escape x as x?html> directives.

```
public static final String ESCAPE_PREFIX = "<#ftl strip_whitespace=true><#escape x as x?html>";

public static final String ESCAPE_SUFFIX = "</#escape>";

ESCAPE_PREFIX + templateText + ESCAPE_SUFFIX
```

Refer:http://freemarker.org/docs/dgui_misc_autoescaping.html

http://watchitlater.com/blog/2011/10/default-html-escape-using-freemarker/

Comment: `#escape` is deprecated in favor of specifying HTML output format. The page that you link writes about that too, not about `#escape`.